# Protect jvm from OutOfMemoryException coming from a java plugin

Tags: java, out-of-memory, sandbox

Is there a way (other than to run the plugin from a separate jvm instance) to prevent a java plugin from crashing the jvm by intentionally/unintentionally eating up the heap and causing an OutOfMemoryException?

I have a mission critical app, and wrote a new feature (plugin) that queues up user requests. For now I've limited the size of the queue, but want to protect the app from malicious/careless programmers that may either remove the size bound on the queue or simply inject code that creates lots of objects to cause an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: what kind of plugin is that?

Comment: If malicious programmers can remove the size limit of the queue, what would stop them from removing any other hypothetical protections you might add?

Comment: @mohammadshamsi its not really a plug-in per se. Its just a sub-app (a new window basically) that lives within the main app. Since I can't have the main app crash, I wanted to sandbox the sub-app properly.

Comment: @DiegoBasch good point. What I'm not too concerned with "malicious" programmers, since only my team members will be contributing to this project. I'm more concerned about careless programming (e.g. someone accidentally deletes the size bound).

Comment: In that case, why not wrap the queue in something like a FixedSizeQueue class, and document why the size bound is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to protect yourself for poorly behaving, buggy or crashing applications is to run it in a separate JVM and communicate with it via messages, rmi or sockets.